# AWS beanstalk PrivateLink not connecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-private-link

I have the following setup

- A single VPC
- 2 Public subnets across 2 AZ (containing AWS Beanstalk app with exposes an api)
- 2 Private subnets across 2 AZ (containing Lambda function)
- 1 Interface VPC Endpoint for Elastic beanstalk (Service name com.amazonaws.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk)

Instead of creating a NAT gateway for my lambda function to be able to access the AWS Beanstalk app  apis over the internet , i want to create a VPC endpoint so that i can access aws beanstalk within AWS internal network from my lambda function.

The public subnet has security groups that allow web traffic (port 80/443)

The VPC endpoint is associated with the private subnets and its security groups allow web traffic traffic(Port 80/443).

The lambda function is also associated with the private subnets and its security groups allow web traffic traffic(Port 80/443).

DNS resolution and DNS hostnames are enabled at VPC level.

I copied the Endpoint dns name to form the url that is being called by the lambda function and i get a timeout

Even after i tried all steps above, AWS Lambda cannot access the beanstalk app api.

Simplified lambda function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'http://vpce-**********.elasticbeanstalk.us-east-2.vpce.amazonaws.com/')
    print(r.data)
    
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

The Elastic beanstalk app is available over the internet at `http://sample-app-dev.******.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/`

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you managed to create a VPC Endpoint which will let you access the Elastic Beanstalk AWS Service (where you can do administration for your EB instances). You did not expose your application itself deployed using Elastic Beanstalk.

I'm saying this, because in order to expose your EB application from a VPC, first you have to create an [Endpoint Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/endpoint-service.html) which connects to a Network Load Balancer. The EB application needs to be registered as a target for this load balancer (which is easy if you have an [Application Load Balancer for EB](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/09/application-load-balancer-aws-privatelink-static-ip-addresses-network-load-balancer/)).
This will give you and service name, from which you can create an Endpoint in the other VPC (consumer VPC), where you can find the service by name:

[image]

If you found your service, you can place and Endpoint into your consumer VPC to which you can connect.

Nevertheless, if both of your VPCs are in the same AWS account, having exposing a service through PrivateLink might be overkill. Probably a [VPC peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html) would suffice.

Update - short tutorial for PrivateLink setup:

1. Create a Network Load Balancer in the VPC in which your EB application is deployed. This will ask you to create a Target Group, so open the link to create one.
2. For the Target Groups for the Load Balancer create a new one and select Application Load Balancer.

[image]

3. Register the load balancer from the EB application to the target group.

[image]

4. Make sure you select the Target Group created before for the network load balancer.

[image]

5. Wait until the load balancer provisions. It should be in the `active` state.

[image]

6. Go to `VPC` -> `Endpoint Service` and create a new `Endpoint Service` (PrivateLink). You will have to give the name of the load balancer here:

[image]

7. Grab the Endpoint Service name:

[image]

8. Go to `Endpoints` and search for the endpoint name:

[image]

9. Attach a security group for the `Endpoint` which allows HTTP/HTTPS inbound traffic from the VPC:

[image]

10. Create the `Endpoints`:

[image]

It might require acceptance, so go back to the `Endpoint Service` and accept the request.

[image]

This should also go from `pending` to `available`.

11. At this point you should be able to access the EB application using the DNS from the `Endpoint`.

Comment: I have an EB application with an Application load balancer.Do i need to create a network load balancer or it would be great if you could expand your explanation or point me to a tutorial

Comment: I managed to create a network load balancer that registers the EB Application load balancer as a target.I can't find the service name

Comment: Thanks for the detailed tutorial.Now when i execute the lambda i don't get a timeout but a new error `Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Comment: Nvm i was using the wrong vpc that's why i was getting the error above

Comment: If my whole infra lives within a single vpc and i don't need to connect to other vpcs , i would still need a vpc endpoint to connect to aws services like dynamoDb ?

Comment: When should i use the aws service vpc endpoint (com.amazonaws.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk).Can you outline what you mean by administer EB instances

Comment: @user2650277 By administration I mean using the `aws cli` and `eb cli`. If you don't have internet connectivity into a VPC, and for some reason you want to use the Elastic Beanstalk API, you can put an Endpoint for `com.amazonaws.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk`.

Comment: DynamoDB is a public service, it does not live inside your VPC. You need an endpoint for it if you don't have internet access or you don't want your traffic to go through the public internet. Other public services are S3, SNS, SQS, CloudWatch, etc.

Comment: I want to put ALB in public subnet(internet facing) and ec2 in private subnets.I created vpc endpoint for aws services as describe in https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-instance-failure/ . Would i need to have a private dns for the interface endpoint for elasticbeanstalk app

Comment: I have created another question related to above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70412803/elastic-beanstalk-setup-with-public-alb-and-ec2-on-private-subnet-falling-health